# Solving inequalities

Tags: inequalities

I would like to solve this problem:

```
smin=Reduce[1000000 Sqrt[2] Abs[1/(a (-2000 + 1000 a))]<=(702.762 s^2)/(Sqrt[
0.25 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2)^2 - 
930.132/s^2] + 
0.5 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2))&&a>0&&a<1,s]
```

but I think this problem requires a lot of time for Mathematica. Is there any way to solve it?

I would like to obtain an explicit solution fos s in terms of a, e.g. s>=...., and then I would like to use this solution into another relation as a multiplier.

Comment: What's the domain of  `s` you're interested in? Reals or complexes?

Comment: I'm interested in s>0

Comment: Then `a>0&&a>1` should be `s>0&&a>1` ?

Comment: Sorry the exact condition is 0<a<1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eqn =
 1000000 Sqrt[2] Abs[
       1/(a (-2000 + 1000 a))] <= (702.762 s^2)/(Sqrt[
         0.25 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 
              930.132/s^2)^2 - 930.132/s^2] + 
        0.5 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2)) // 
    Rationalize // Simplify[#, 0 < a < 1] & // Simplify[#, s > 0] &

(* -((1000*Sqrt[2])/((-2 + a)*a)) <= (28110480*s^4)/(18602640 + 
        304981*s + 18000*s^2 + Sqrt[346058214969600 + 
            11346903499680*s - 725502749639*s^2 + 
            10979316000*s^3 + 324000000*s^4]) *)
```

`Simplify` is used twice rather than combining them in order to accelerate the simplification.

```
smin = Reduce[eqn && 0 < a < 1 && s > 0, s] // N

(* (Inequality[0., Less, a, LessEqual, 0.00010315517885076623] && 
      s >= Root[155022000000000 + (-108943570764000*Sqrt[2]*
                     a + 54471785382000*Sqrt[2]*a^2)*#1^2 + 
              (-1786075479350*Sqrt[2]*a + 893037739675*Sqrt[2]*a^2)*
                #1^3 + (-105414300000*Sqrt[2]*a + 52707150000*
                     Sqrt[2]*a^2)*#1^4 + (164624809548*a^2 - 
                   164624809548*a^3 + 41156202387*a^4)*#1^6 & , 
          4]) || (0.00010315517885076623 < a < 
        0.008304821610873913 && s >= Root[155022000000000 + 
              (-108943570764000*Sqrt[2]*a + 54471785382000*
                     Sqrt[2]*a^2)*#1^2 + (-1786075479350*Sqrt[2]*a + 
                   893037739675*Sqrt[2]*a^2)*#1^3 + (-105414300000*
                     Sqrt[2]*a + 52707150000*Sqrt[2]*a^2)*#1^4 + 
              (164624809548*a^2 - 164624809548*a^3 + 
                   41156202387*a^4)*#1^6 & , 2]) || (Inequality[
        0.008304821610873913, LessEqual, a, Less, 1.] && 
      s >= Root[155022000000000 + (-108943570764000*Sqrt[2]*
                     a + 54471785382000*Sqrt[2]*a^2)*#1^2 + 
              (-1786075479350*Sqrt[2]*a + 893037739675*Sqrt[2]*a^2)*
                #1^3 + (-105414300000*Sqrt[2]*a + 52707150000*
                     Sqrt[2]*a^2)*#1^4 + (164624809548*a^2 - 
                   164624809548*a^3 + 41156202387*a^4)*#1^6 & , 4]) *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
Clear[f, f2]

f[a_?NumericQ] := Evaluate@Piecewise[{#[[2]], #[[1]]} & /@ (List @@ smin)];

tab = {#, f[#]} & /@ Append[Range[1/40., 39/40., 1/40.], 0.999];

Multicolumn[
 StringForm["a = `1`, `2`",
    NumberForm[#[[1]], {4, 3}],
    NumberForm[#[[2]], {7, 5}]] & /@ tab,
 2, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

```
pts = {#[[1]], #[[2, -1]]} & /@ tab;
```

You can use [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html), [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html), or [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) to convert `pts` to a polynomial in `a`.

```
n = 10; (* order of polynomial *)

coef = Array[c, n + 1];

model = coef.a^Range[0, n];

f2[a_] = NonlinearModelFit[pts, model, coef, a][a]

(* 18.9537 - 218.369 a + 2436.68 a^2 - 16624.1 a^3 + 71222.6 a^4 - 197425. a^5 + 
 358850. a^6 - 424275. a^7 + 313931. a^8 - 131934. a^9 + 24023.7 a^10 *)

Plot[{f[a][[-1]], f2[a]}, {a, 0, 1},
 Filling -> {1 -> Top},
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.3, LightBlue],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {a, s}),
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[2], Point[pts]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.75, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I really do appreciate your help. How can I extract from this output the analytical expression?
e.g. s>=a^3+3a+2 ---------- I would obtain  a^3+3a+2

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see how it looks, you could try

```
r = 10;
R = ImplicitRegion[
   1000000 Sqrt[2] Abs[
       1/(a (-2000 + 1000 a))] <= (702.762 s^2)/(Sqrt[
         0.25 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 
              930.132/s^2)^2 - 930.132/s^2] + 
        0.5 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2)) && 
    a > 0 && a > 1,
   {{a, -r, r}, {s, -r, r}}];
DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the approach by @HenrikSchumacher is using a `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[{1000000 Sqrt[2] Abs[1/(a (-2000 + 1000 a))] -
   (702.762 s^2)/(Sqrt[
       0.25 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2)^2 - 
        930.132/s^2] +
      0.5 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2))},
 {s, -10, 10}, {a, 1, 5}, Contours -> {0}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"s", "a"}]
```

[image: Contour plot of inequality]

The "blue" area is where the inequality is satisfied.

It is likely that you'll need to set values for `a` and solve for `s` (or vice versa) numerically. And there's a problem of dividing by zero when `a = 2`.

**Update:**  The OP has updated the question to restrict the values of `s` and `a`.

```
ContourPlot[{1000000 Sqrt[2] Abs[1/(a (-2000 + 1000 a))] -
   (702.762 s^2)/(Sqrt[
       0.25 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2)^2 - 
        930.132/s^2] +
      0.5 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2))},
 {s, 0, 20}, {a, 0, 1}, Contours -> {0}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"s", "a"}]
```

[image: Contour plot of updated inequality]

Comment: Thanks, I would like to obtain the relation between s and a

Comment: You can certainly solve for `a` in terms of `s` but not the other way around.

Comment: Is it possible to solve for s in terms of a?

Comment: You can certainly solve for `s` for specific values of `a` (numerically) but I don't think there's a general explicit solution.  If you described (in your original question - rather than in comments) your expected use of such a solution, then maybe an approximation might satisfy that need.  This seems likely because of the restricted range of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

If the equation (ContourPlot answer JimB) is squared one can solve for a

```
eq = Simplify[(1000000 Sqrt[2] Abs[
    1/(a (-2000 + 1000 a))])^2 == ((702.762 s^2)/(Sqrt[
      0.25 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 
           930.132/s^2)^2 - 930.132/s^2] + 
     0.5 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 
        930.132/s^2)))^2 /. Abs[z_]^2 -> z^2]
erga = Simplify[Solve[%, a]];
Plot[a /. erga, {s, 0, 20}, AxesLabel -> {s, a}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}]
```

[image]

Obviously only `s=Function[a]`is well defined(s>0).

Answer (score -1):

`FindInstance` is your friend

```
eq = Rationalize[
   1000000 Sqrt[2] Abs[1/(a (-2000 + 1000 a))] <= (702.762 s^2)/(Sqrt[
        0.25 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2)^2 - 
         930.132/s^2] + 0.5 (1 + 0.5 (-0.2 + 30.4981 Sqrt[1/s^2]) + 930.132/s^2)), 0];
FindInstance[eq && 0 < a < 1 && s > 0, {s, a}]
{{s -> 256, a -> 3/65536}}

eq /. %
{True}
```

Comment: That gives only one value, it does actually solve the equation (whose solution set is a curve).